# Extract numbers after the specific words

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract numbers (without the commas) from a HTML code. This is the part with the numbers I'm after. I want to extract numbers after the string "Owners estimation: "

```
<p style="font-size: 150%;margin-bottom:10px" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Estimation is the process of finding an estimate or approximation, which is a value that is usable for some purpose even if input data may be incomplete, uncertain, or unstable. The value is nonetheless usable because it is derived from the best information available.">Owners estimation: 4,253,717</p>
```

I would like to end up with: 4253717

I would appricate a help with this.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't _parse_ your HTML content and search for the estimation number that way?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How does that make it easier? The only difference is whether you search the whole string or the `.innerHTML`. The regexp is the same, unless you need to ensure that it doesn't match inside the tag.

Comment: A regexp can't omit the commas, because it always matches a contiguous string. You'll have to remove the commas after you match.

Comment: @Barmar Who says the OP is using JS?  And some parsers can deliver just the tag content, from which a very simple regex could return the number of interest.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Replace that with whatever is analogous in the language they're using. The point is that he doesn't seem to know how to write that "very simple regex"

Comment: I'm using JS and I could remove commas after the match

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=Owners estimation: )(.*)(?=</p>)
```

Found out how to do it. Works like I wanted.